# @"" string type literals for NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, macros, nsnumber, objective-c-literals

I love the shorthand handling of string literals in Objective C with the `@"string"` notation. Is there any way to get similar behavior with `NSNumber`s? I deal with numbers more and it's so tedious having `[NSNumber numberWithWhatever:]` calls everywhere. Even creating a macro would work, but my knowledge of how best to do that is limited.

Comment: As pointed out by rjstelling, this is now a feature in clang. Much rejoicing. Please vote to close, thanks.

Comment: There's no need to close this. It's a perfectly valid question. Closure is for undesirable questions, where answers need to be prevented.

Comment: You should accept @rjstelling's answer instead though as it is more correct now.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what the SO perspective on that is. Tilo answered the question as it was at that time so it seems a bit unfair to award it to another person after the facts changed. Like discounting von Neumann because he didn't foresee multi-cores or something. At 1542 views over three years this question isn't exactly even getting used that much. In addition, I think Tilo's answer and JeremyP's improvements could still be useful to someone maybe looking for NSSet literal syntax or NSMutableArray literal syntax workarounds however unlikely they are to show up here looking towards that end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using a macro like

```
#define N(x) [NSNumber numberWithInt: x]
```

wich leads to code like

```
[N(123) intValue];
```

**update:**

One should be aware of the CPU and memory consumption of such a macro. While the `@"…"` strings are **static** compiler generated strings of the constant string class (depends on foundation maybe `NSConstantString` in Cocoa?) the macros create code which is evaluated at runtime and therefore create a new object every time they are called.

Comment: Slight improvement: `#define N(x) [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: @"" #x]`.  Will allow you to do things like `N(1.4)` or `N(1E09)`

Comment: Yes, but isn't it significant slower? I'm using an `F(x)` macro for floating points which invokes `[NSNumber numberWithDouble: x]`.

Answer (score 33):

Since nobody has mentioned this... If you need to wrap a value in an NSNumber, the NSNumber literal syntax is as follows.

```
int val = 13;
NSNumber *numVal = @(val);
```

Comment: Hi Adam, good point. Even after the new syntax came out this was not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: Is there a shorthand for the opposite? A way to get intValue off of an NSNumber?

Comment: it works, but is little bit "cryptic" or obvious for me to use it.

Answer (score 31):

As of [Clang v3.1](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) you can now use Objective-C literals.

```
NSNumber *fortyTwo = @42;             // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithInt:42]
NSNumber *fortyTwoUnsigned = @42U;    // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:42U]
NSNumber *fortyTwoLong = @42L;        // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithLong:42L]
NSNumber *fortyTwoLongLong = @42LL;   // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:42LL]
```

So, answering your specific question:

```
[Tyler setArms:[[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1] autorelease]];
```

Can now be written as:

```
[Tyler setArms:@1];
```

There are also literals for arrays and dictionaries, but they are beyond the scope of this question.

To take advantage of literals in Xcode you'll need at least version 4.4 -- this comes with Apple's LLVM 4.0 compiler.

Comment: Yes, very exciting! Also, I'm going to close this question before a million people tell me I'm an idiot.

Comment: @rob5408 no one will think your an idiot, it is a valid question and you asked about it almost 2 years before it was available. You get a +1 from me.

Comment: There is no corresponding shortcut for a variable of type NSInteger, float, double, so on?

Answer (score 7):

Xcode 4.4 has introduced the Clang features that [rjstelling mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11120405/418715) for literals for `NSNumber`, `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. The syntax is simple:

```
//Number literal
NSNumber *pi = @3.14;

//Array literal
NSArray *primes = @[ @2, @3, @5, @7, @11 ]; //No nil terminator needed

//Dictionary literal
NSDictionary *dict = @{
    @"key1": @42,
    @"key2": @"Another key",
    @3: @"A NSNumber key"
}; //No nil terminator, stored in "key:value," format
```